# Pivoting Varchar Value to column

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, sql-server-2016

I am trying to pivot this data set in SQL Server 2016

--Dataset

```
CarModel    Tire              MakeDate   Owner

Subaru       MRF             20200101     John D
Subaru       Goodyear        20200101     John D
Subaru       MRF             20200101     John D
Subaru       MRF             20200101     John D
```

The output result should be :

```
CarModel Tire1 Tire2     Tire3 Tire4 MakeDate    Owner
Subaru   MRF   GoodYear  MRF    MRF   20200101    John D
```

I tried this but with no success. Can you please let me know if I am making any mistakes ?

```
create table #temp_Dataset 
(Carmodel varchar(10), Tire varchar(10), MakeDate int, [Owner] Varchar(10))

insert into #temp_Dataset
(Carmodel, Tire, MakeDate, [Owner])
values 
('Subaru',       'MRF',             20200101 ,    'John D'),
('Subaru',       'Goodyear',        20200101 ,    'John D'),
('Subaru',       'MRF',             20200101 ,    'John D'),
('Subaru',       'MRF',             20200101 ,    'John D')

Select * from( 
 SELECT CarModel,
       Tire,
       MakeDate,
       [Owner]
FROM #temp_Dataset)a
pivot (max(carmodel) for Tire in (Tire1, Tire2, Tire3, Tire4))piv

drop table #temp_Dataset
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed to enumerate the tires and use wrong argument(`[Carmodel]`) within the `MAX` aggregation. Prefer using such as

```
SELECT * 
  FROM( 
       SELECT *,
              CONCAT('Tire',ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
             (PARTITION BY [Carmodel], [MakeDate], [Owner] ORDER BY [CarModel])) AS [rn]
         FROM #temp_Dataset
      ) AS ds
  PIVOT(
        MAX([Tire]) FOR [rn] IN ([Tire1],[Tire2],[Tire3],[Tire4])
       ) AS piv
```

Btw, the four tires will be ordered arbitrarly in the current case, you can change as desired through changing the columns within the `ORDER BY` clause.

You can even make the pivoting dynamic in order to add or subtract the values of the tires when grouped by the other columns such as

```
DECLARE @cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),  @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
                
SELECT @cols = 
       STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(CONCAT('Tire',[rn])) AS formulas
                FROM 
                (
                 SELECT *, 
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                        (PARTITION BY [Carmodel], [MakeDate], [Owner] ORDER BY [CarModel]) AS rn
                   FROM [#temp_Dataset]
                ) ff
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');
        
SET  @query =
          N'SELECT * 
              FROM( 
                   SELECT *,
                          CONCAT(''Tire'',
                          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Carmodel], [MakeDate], [Owner] ORDER BY [CarModel])) AS [rn]
                     FROM [#temp_Dataset]
                  ) AS ds
             PIVOT(
                   MAX([Tire]) FOR [rn] IN (' + @cols + N' )
                  ) AS piv'

EXEC sp_executesql @query;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=f9757467f21cc5c0d0cf817358277291)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation and `row_number()`:

```
select carmodel, makedate, owner,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then tire end) as tire_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then tire end) as tire_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then tire end) as tire_3,
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then tire end) as tire_4
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by carmodel, makedate, owner order by ?) as seqnum
      from #temp_Dataset t
     ) t
group by carmodel, makedate, owner;
```

The `?` is for the ordering of the columns. It is not obvious what order you want the results in -- and SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.